# C# ASP.NET CORE and sending FormFile to client app

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have an Angular that has a component that is using text editor CKEditor 5. I installed it and added plugin SimpleUpload. When I add an image to the editor it is send to my API that is responsible for storing it in database and then sending url back to editor.
Request looks like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKvgJ.jpg)
Here is my action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostImage()
    {
        if (Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var myFile = Request.Form.Files[0].OpenReadStream();
            
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                myFile.CopyTo(ms);

                Image newImage = new Image
                {
                    Id = default,
                    ImageData = ms.ToArray()
                };

                var res = await blogAppDbContext.Images.AddAsync(newImage);
                await blogAppDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                string imageUrl = 
                      $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}/api/image/{res.Entity.Id}";
                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        url = imageUrl,
                    });
            }

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    "Error occured during posting image");
    }
```

and then I get response with the url. Everything seems fine.
The problem occurs when CKEditor is trying to retrive the image with url.
Here is the method:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetImage(long id)
    {
        var myImage = await blogAppDbContext.Images.FindAsync(id);
        if (myImage != null && myImage.ImageData != null)
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(myImage.ImageData);
            var file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, "", "my.jpg")
            {
                Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                ContentDisposition = "form-data"
            };

            return Ok(file);
        }

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                                "Error occured during retriving image");
    }
```

and the response:

```
{
"contentDisposition":"form-data",
"contentType":"image/jpeg",
"headers":{
      "Content-Type":["image/jpeg"],
      "Content-Disposition":["form-data"]
},
"length":47028,
"name":"",
"fileName":"my.jpg"
}
```

The image in CKEditor appears blank and it looks like no data is send.

Comment: `FormFile` is for sening to server ... maybe youshould use `FileResult` (to return file directly)

Comment: @Selvin It worked. Thank you a lot. To think I spent so much time on this and the solution is so simple. Didn't thought that I would need different type.